# store crf Tagger in python

Tags: python, nlp, crf

```
crf_tagger = CRFTagger()
crf_tagger.train(train_sents,'/tmp/crf_tagger.model')
#Store CRFT.
from pickle import dump
output = open('crfTagger.pkl', 'wb')
dump(crf_tagger, output, -1)
output.close()
```

When I ran the part above, then got:

> TypeError: self.c_tagger cannot be converted to a Python object for
> pickling

It was fine if I use another model

Comment: What library are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle cannot dump Python objects. Use dill instead of pickle: https://pypi.org/project/dill/.